# Wi-Fi connection dissapeared after boot

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

today I booted my pc and wifi dissapeared.
Yesterday it worked good. I'm kinda new to Linux (2 months). I use Kubuntu 22.04 with USB network adapter TL-WN822N.

**sudo lshw -C network** output:

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: d4:3d:7e:27:27:ae
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.18.18-xanmod1 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@2:1.3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 5a:4f:3a:25:50:07
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.18.18-xanmod1 duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=*cant show* link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

When I installed the system (10.08) I installed (or not) driver RTL8192CU (rtl8192eu didn't work), because it couldn't work without driver. Internet started working, I checked driver version and it was r8169. Then I thinked "Oh, doesn't matter, it works anyway".

Today I tried reinstalling network manager (KDE's one), but it didn't work.

To be honest, I think that's driver issue.
My xanmod version is 5.18.18, drivers below installed to previous versions

output of **dkms status** command (hope this helps well):

```
8192cu/1.11, 5.18.16-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
8192cu/1.11, 5.18.17-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu/1.0, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu/1.0, 5.18.16-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu/1.0, 5.18.17-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
```

Any possible solutions and questions? And yes, write answers, so that I could understand (im newb).

**upd1:**
So I uninstalled all drivers from dkms status. Then I tried to reinstall rtl8192cu, but after typing `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11` it gave me this:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.18.18-xanmod1 -C /lib/modules/5.18.18-xanmod1/build M=/var/lib/dkms/8192cu/1.11/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8192cu: 1.11 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.18.18-xanmod1 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8192cu/1.11/build/make.log for more information.
```

I saw someone fixing it by editing dkms.conf (other rtl drivers), but I can't figure out how.

`cat /var/lib/dkms/8192cu/1.11/build/make.log`
output: https://pastebin.com/GqudRXJQ (too long)

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2357:0108 TP-Link TL-WN822N Version 4 RTL8192EU
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:0017 SINOWEALTH Game Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: It looks like `r8169` is Ethernet not WIFI. Have you tried running `sudo modprobe 8192cu` to load the driver?

Comment: `modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192cu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.18.18-xanmod1`
it's installed only in 5.18.16 and 5.18.17 versions of xanmod (check dkms status);
seems like xanmod got an update and I need to install that driver too again, but how?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "I use Kubuntu 22.04" It appeards that you are actually running XanMod which is not an official Ubuntu flavor. May we see: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Done. I need to install driver, but I cant (check upd1)

Comment: The driver is incompatible with the kernel. Boot with an Ubuntu kernel and install the driver.

Comment: driver worked good with xanmod even on linux mint, it is not the problem

Comment: @Pilot6 has given you the correct answer. We can't help you with a kernel from XanMod and an incompatible gcc system from Debian. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe it "worked good" but now it doesn't build ;-)

Comment: sounds very sad, I really hope I will be able to install rtl8192cu after that;
if I won't be able to do that, I will make new question

Comment: i've succesfully uninstalled xanmod kernel and got back to `5.15.0-46-generic` kernel, i've successfully installed driver, but there is still no wifi connection, i used https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes driver

Comment: FIXED! i've installed rtl8192**eu** driver, thanks everyone!